# Metamask - Infura problem. Cannot read property 'currentProvider' of undefined

Tags: metamask, javascript, infura, web3-providers

I got a problem. I  am using code below to connect to the eth from node.js app. Everything works perfect as long as I have installed MetaMask in my browser. I can be logged in, logged out, all good when I fetch the data. Problems comes when I uninstall MetaMask. It writes, that currentProvider is undefined.
Is there a workaroud? What am I doing wrong?

System: Windows ''
Browsers: Brave, Chrome, Opera (havent tried others)
Node version: 8.12.
web3 version:  1.0.0-beta.46

```
import Web3 from 'web3';

var web3;

if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.web3 !== 'undefined') { 
    web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider); 
} else { 
    const provider = new   Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/...' );
    web3 = new Web3(provider); 
} 
export default web3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Anyway. I use next.js so the page is initially rendered at the server side. I fetch there, using infura, all the necessary info which works perfectly. The page is shown properly for a second. Then nextjs renders the page again at client side which causes the problem coz window is defined but window.web3 is not. I solved this simply by

```
import Web3 from 'web3';

    var web3;

    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        if(window.web3 !== 'undefined'){
            const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
                'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/...'
                );
            web3 = new Web3(provider);
        } else{
            web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
        }
    } else {
        const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
            'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/...'
            );
        web3 = new Web3(provider);
    }

    export default web3;
```